# How does one set text of two labels with two different cultural/region format options?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, regioninfo

How does one set text of two labels with two different cultural/region format options?
For first label to be `ar-EG : Arabic - Egypt`
and second one to be `en-US : English - United States` ?

This to be done for Number/Date/Time/Currency formats.

Answer (score 1):

Use the culture explicitly in the ToString() method.  For example:

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
  CultureInfo arabic = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-EG");
  label1.Text = dt.ToString(arabic.DateTimeFormat);
  CultureInfo english = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
  label2.Text = dt.ToString(english.DateTimeFormat);
```

Use CultureInfo.NumberFormat to format numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this maybe can solve your problem:

I needed to show different money values in two differents cultural format. So i did this right after each of the code-line asingning the value:

```
CultureInfo US = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = US;

// Asign your label here

CultureInfo AR = new CultureInfo("ar-EG");  
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = AR;

//Asign label here
```

Just remember to add the folowing namespace to the top of your code-file:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
```

and to re-set the previous culture. You can even override the System culture info just by adding those lines on the program.cs

Comment: This doesn't work in case of Number, it always show US format?

Comment: Actually, it should do, it works with me(using es-CR and en-US). Remember that code gets the cultural config from the OS, so if you have configured your "ar-EG" diferently as it should be, it will take that paramethers to format your currency/dates and so on...